# Low video quality with h264_omx encoder

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, ffmpeg, h264

I have a Logitech C922 webcam and I'm recording using ffmpeg with this settings:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -f alsa -r 16000 -i hw:1,0 -f video4linux2 -thread_queue_size 512 -s 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -r 5 -f mp4 -vcodec h264_omx -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k output.mp4
```

However, the video output quality seems to be very low. Is there a way to increase it? Thanks!